# GooglePlacesAutocomplete returning the same address to both the textviews-your starting point and your destination

Tags: java, android

I am new to StackOverflow so apologies for any mistakes. The problem I am stuck on is, whenever i use GooglePlacesAutocomplete Activity in my android app and when I type the address it fills both the textviews.While i want it to work in a way that whenever i click "your starting point" which takes me to the placesautocomplete activity and the typed address should get filled only in "your starting point" textview and then similar with "your destination".

So how to do it?And also how to get "Today" or "Tomorrow" instead of "date-month-year" in Datetextview.I am also attaching the screenshot for a better understanding.

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_find_sameway_rides);

    eet1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eet1);
    eet2 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eet2);

    eet1.setOnClickListener(this);
    eet2.setOnClickListener(this);

    // Open the autocomplete activity when the TextView is clicked.
    TextView openTextview = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eet1);
    assert openTextview != null;
    openTextview.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == eet1)
            openAutocompleteActivity();
        }

    });


    // Open the autocomplete activity when the TextView is clicked.
    TextView openTextView = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.eet2);
    assert openTextView != null;
    openTextView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if (v == eet2)
            openAutocompleteActivity();
        }

    });

    timetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.timetext);
    datetext = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.datetext);

    timetext.setOnClickListener(this);
    datetext.setOnClickListener(this);

}

protected void openAutocompleteActivity() {
    try {
        // The autocomplete activity requires Google Play Services to be available. The intent
        // builder checks this and throws an exception if it is not the case.
        Intent intent = new PlaceAutocomplete.IntentBuilder(PlaceAutocomplete.MODE_FULLSCREEN)
                .build(this);
        startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesRepairableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is either not installed or not up to date. Prompt
        // the user to correct the issue.
        GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorDialog(this, e.getConnectionStatusCode(),
                0 /* requestCode */).show();
    } catch (GooglePlayServicesNotAvailableException e) {
        // Indicates that Google Play Services is not available and the problem is not easily
        // resolvable.
        String message = "Google Play Services is not available: " +
                GoogleApiAvailability.getInstance().getErrorString(e.errorCode);

        Log.e(TAG, message);
        Toast.makeText(this, message, Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

/**
 * Called after the autocomplete activity has finished to return its result.
 */
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.e(TAG, "Place: " + place.getAddress());

            assert findViewById(R.id.eet1) != null;
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.eet1))
                    .setText(place.getName() + ",\n" +
                            place.getAddress());


        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
            // the user pressed the back button.
        }
    }

    // Check that the result was from the autocomplete widget.
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE_AUTOCOMPLETE) {
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            // Get the user's selected place from the Intent.
            Place place = PlaceAutocomplete.getPlace(this, data);
            Log.e(TAG, "Place: " + place.getAddress());

            assert findViewById(R.id.eet2) != null;
            ((TextView) findViewById(R.id.eet2))
                    .setText(place.getName() + ",\n" +
                            place.getAddress());


        } else if (resultCode == PlaceAutocomplete.RESULT_ERROR) {
            Status status = PlaceAutocomplete.getStatus(this, data);
            Log.e(TAG, "Error: Status = " + status.toString());
        } else if (resultCode == RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // Indicates that the activity closed before a selection was made. For example if
            // the user pressed the back button.
        }
    }
}

@Override
public void onClick(View v) {
    if (v == datetext) {

        // Process to get Current Date
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mYear = c.get(Calendar.YEAR);
        mMonth = c.get(Calendar.MONTH);
        mDay = c.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);

        // Launch Date Picker Dialog
        DatePickerDialog dpd = new DatePickerDialog(this,
                new DatePickerDialog.OnDateSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onDateSet(DatePicker view, int year,
                                          int monthOfYear, int dayOfMonth) {
                        // Display Selected date in textbox
                        datetext.setText(dayOfMonth + "-"
                                + (monthOfYear + 1) + "-" + year);

                    }
                }, mYear, mMonth, mDay);
        dpd.show();
    }
    if (v == timetext) {

        // Process to get Current Time
        final Calendar c = Calendar.getInstance();
        mHour = c.get(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY);
        mMinute = c.get(Calendar.MINUTE);

        // Launch Time Picker Dialog
        TimePickerDialog tpd = new TimePickerDialog(this,
                new TimePickerDialog.OnTimeSetListener() {

                    @Override
                    public void onTimeSet(TimePicker view, int hourOfDay,
                                          int minute) {
                        // Display Selected time in textbox
                        timetext.setText(hourOfDay + ":" + minute);
                    }
                }, mHour, mMinute, false);
        tpd.show();
    }
}
```

Comment: Not able to upload the screenshot!

Comment: Issue has been resolved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You got problem because of in your **onActivityResult** method, you wrote code for both TextView. So whenever user pick the place, both TextViews are filled simultaneously.

Comment: I accept it for your generous efforts as the issue has already been resolved but i forgot to close the question.